# How do I create a custom text data source for a custom file type that renders text in default text editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have a file type that has a custom extension that is essentially a zip file with multiple files inside, including a .json file. Is it possible to create an extension that provides all the background code necessary to read/write to that json file using VSCode's default text editor view (with syntax highlighting, format document, collapsible grouping, etc.)?

I've looked into using a `CustomTextEditorProvider`, but that wants to handle the file management itself, and I think it requires me to provide my own `webview` content. Not what I want.

The `CustomEditorProvider` was slightly better. I was able to get it to load my data and render the contents in a `webview`, but again, this requires me to provide my own `webview` content instead of just using VSCode's built-in text editor view. Again, not what I want.

I also looked into the `TextDocumentContentProvider` as that seemed to be what I want, with a overridable method called `provideTextDocumentContent`. But this appears to be designed for handling URIs with custom schemas, not file extensions.

Any thoughts or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: you need to write a File System extension, that acts like a remote workspace

Comment: That looks interesting. But it looks like it is registered for a URI scheme, not a file extension. Is there a way I'm missing to register it for a file extension?

Comment: you can create a **Multi Root Workspace** and place these zip files as additional workspaces